# SQL Server Key Value Data Model

Tags: sql, sql-server, data-modeling, hierarchical-data

I'm currently in a project that involves doing migrations, basically we have a staging table, which is a flat table that will have all the data loaded by an external service, and later all its data will be moved to a normalized database (with several tables) through stored procedures.These normalized tables are system-versioned temporal table where we have the history of them all.

We are thinking of using a hierarchical type of data model because of a problem we are going to have with the current data model. That's why we think the key value data model fits our project. Basically we are thinking of having a table like this:

| ID | Key | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | Test 1 |
| 2 | 2 | Test 2 |
| 3 | 3 | Test 3 |
| 4 | 4 | Test 4 |

Then we'll have a table with all the keys:

| Key | Table_Name | Name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Test_Table | Name |
| 2 | Test_Table | Last_Name |
| 3 | Test_Table | Address |
| 4 | Test_Table | Telephone |

Why do we want to try to adopt this solution? Because changes may occur to our data model, for example, we may have to remove a column from one table to put in another or add new columns in a specific table. When this happens we'll have problems in the system-versioned temporal table because once that column is removed and moved to another table we won't have the history of the changes and the same happens if we add a new column...

By using key-value we can add a new column (key) and move it without any problem because we only have to do it in one table and our main table never changes at schema level and we can preserve the history of the table.

I know that these tables are more used for "NoSQL" and I know that maybe it's not a good idea to use this solution (I have read in many places that it is not good practice to use them), that's why I wanted ideas to know what is the best decision to take in this case. If you know solutions to keep the data with the initial solution (normalized) and ways to overcome the fact that new columns can be added as well as moved somewhere else and not messing up the history tables would be perfect.

Comment: Google "EAV anti-pattern".

Comment: Entity-Attribute-Value / EAV is an anti-pattern design regardless if you use a SQL or NoSQL database. If you're concerned about maintaining history in your temporal tables when the schema changes, then you should ask that as a question instead. There are solutions to that problem which will be much less problematic than using an EAV design in the long run.

Comment: Thanks! I'm seeing now the "Anchor Modeling" and I think can be a good solution but is a bit difficult to implement...

Comment: @J.D. what type of solution can I apply? I can't find anything helpful in stackoverflow.

Comment: @tg_dev3 for starters, [most schema changes are permissable with temporal tables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/changing-the-schema-of-a-system-versioned-temporal-table?view=sql-server-ver16#important-remarks), such as adding columns. If you need to do something more extreme like migrating a column from one table to another with the history from its correlating temporal table to the new correlating temporal table, then you just have to set `SYSTEM_VERSIONING` off, make the appropriate DDL / DML changes, and turn it back on, like in the example in the docs.

Comment: Thanks a lot @J.D. Regarding the "Anchor Modeling", do you have some opinion?

Comment: @tg_dev3 No problem. I've never heard of that term. Do you have a resource about it that I can read?

Comment: @J.D. https://www.anchormodeling.com/